# fuerte machine tag changes

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rep 124 describes the changes made in the machine tag syntax in the ROS fuerte release [1], and states:

The env-loader file must be an executable script that accepts variable-length arguments. After performing environment setup, the script must then execute its arguments as a command. ROS installations come with a default environment loader file.

Can someone give an example of how such a script would typically look like?

[1] http://ros.org/reps/rep-0124.html#machine-tag

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31291/fuerte-machine-tag-changes/) by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2012-04-05

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't really get how this script works. Executing it once prints the first echo statement, executing it a second time only prints the second statement. Must be my lack of bash script understanding.

Anyway, I put together a simple script that does the job for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ROS_ROOT=<ros-root>
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=<ros-package-path>
export ROS_IP=<ip>
export ROS_MASTER_URI=<master-uri>

exec "$@"
```

This script should be placed on the **remote** computer. In the machine file, remove all definitions of ros-* variables, and use the env-loader="" attribute, e.g.

```
<launch>
  <machine name="<machine-name>" env-loader="<path-to-env-script>" address="<remote-ip>" user="<username>">
  </machine>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A good question. I don't know a good answer.

We can get some hints from the default script provided in `/opt/ros/fuerte/env.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    /bin/echo "Entering environment at /opt/ros/fuerte"
    . /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.sh
    $SHELL
    /bin/echo "Exiting build environment at /opt/ros/fuerte"
else
    . /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.sh
    exec "$@"
fi
```

I suspect that one could add additional environment definitions using a similar script.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1